# Apache problems in performance test with mod_reqtimeout

Tags: firewall, apache-2.4, jboss, ajp, mod-reqtimeout

We have 2 Apache webserver behind a load balancer wich are connected to 2 (JBoss) application servers via mod ajp.

To those webservers, mobile devices connect via a REST API.

In our performance test we rather quickly ran into a lot of NonHttpResponse: errors which we identified to be coming from mod_reqtimeout:

```
[Mon Mar 16 14:42:49.324705 2015] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 27914:tid 140628428449536] [client 1.2.3.4:48280] AH01382: Request header read timeout
```

... which is configured as follows:

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
    RequestReadTimeout header=10-20,minrate=500
    RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500
</IfModule>
```

I was able to get rid of those errors by increasing those values to

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-60,minrate=100
```

But this can't be the solution, since with some more simultaneous users the problem occured again (There is a requirement to be able to serve 300 concurrent users - 100 worked quite ok, with 300 we had over 10,000 of those Request header read timeout errors). I suspect it's the interaction of apaches KeepAlive, our mod_ajp configuration and mod_reqtimeout that leads mod_reqtimeout to the conclusion that there is a slowloris attack ongoing (to many open connections that do nothing) and I kindly ask for your help in tweaking those parameters.

Additional problem is a firewall between webserver and application server, which I suspect to kill open idle connections. I read about deactivating KeepAlive completely to solve this, but as I said, all our clients are mobile devices, so that's probably not an option (?).

Here are the other configs (parts of):

workers.properties:

```
worker.list=server
worker.maintain=60

worker.server.type=ajp13
worker.server.host=server
worker.server.port=15869
worker.server.socket_keepalive=True
worker.server.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.server.ping_mode=A
worker.server.connection_ping_interval=60
```

mod_prefork:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers         5
    MinSpareServers      5
    MaxSpareServers     10
    #MaxClients         256
    MaxClients         300
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

mainserver.conf:

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

ssl.conf (mobile devices connect via ssl):

```
Timeout 1200
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 10
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual that you are using "prefork" MPM in what seems to be essentially a reverse-proxy, the hybrid "worker" MPM has better scalability, that's not the problem though.

DoS mitigation is usually best handled (if not by your ISP) on the *front-end* device that terminates the client requests, from your description this is a load-balancer, not Apache. Any competent load balancer will be HTTP aware (i.e. "Layer 7"), this will likely result in buffering of HTTP requests. This also applies if the load-balancer is terminating HTTPS, but less so if the load-balancer is simply relaying the HTTPS connections (as it cannot see the HTTP requests to buffer them). Nor does it apply if your load-balancer is a simple "Layer 3/4" NAT type load-balancer.

As to the possible cause of the timeouts:

- your SSL instance `KeepAliveTimeout` is the same as the `RequestReadTimeout` header read timeout, it's possible there's a race where keepalive timeout is reached mid-way through the incoming client request/headers. If I try to reproduce this, in addition to AH01382 errors I also get  AH01991 (SSL input filter read failed)and AH00567 (request failed: error reading the headers). This may not explain all the problems though.
- malformed client requests, not uncommon in the past (e.g. extra CR/LF after POST, incomplete requests when retrying after error). I don't know of anything current though, it depends on your client base, and more importantly, their connectivity.
- there could be a bug similar to [this recent one](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56216) which caused spurious timeouts with "event" MPM.

To reproduce timeouts:

```
 $ openssl s_client -connect myhost:443
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: myhost.whatever.com 

 [server reply goes here]
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host:
```

You can script this to make it easier, otherwise you must type/paste the first request and headers within your configured 10s, then type *but not complete* the second request within the next 10s, you must have at least one full line (the request) submitted for the second request, then just wait.

Decreasing the KeepAliveTimeout (default is 5 seconds) may help. Note that KeepAliveTimeout is the time to receive a  complete a request.
I think the next step may be [`mod_log_forensic`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html).

Regarding the connections to the back-end via AJP, are you using "ping" on the [Apache `Balancer` configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html)? If I understand your system correctly, the Tomcat configuration you have given won't apply to connections from Apache httpd to Tomcat. See [the options here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

```
                          /-> apache httpd + ajp -\            /-> tomcat/jboss
client -> load-balancer  <                         > firewall <
                          \-> apache httpd + ajp -/            \-> tomcat/jboss
```

Comment: Wow - thank you very much for your detailed answer! I haven't been able to implement your suggestions yet. I'll be back as soon as I do. Thanks again!!